# How to extract array from array?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have 2d array

```
arr = [[1, 2, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 4, 4, 4],
       [1, 4, 8, 4],
       [1, 4, 4, 4]]
```

What is the best way to extract that array with lots of 4s
when I know only the top left corner indexes?

```
arr[1][2]
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Make a new smaller 3x3 array.

Comment: Do you, perchance, look to find a submatrix from a 2D array?

Comment: Why the rush to select an answer? For one, it's a discourtesy to others who are still preparing answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
arr[2, 3].map { |row| row[1, 3] }
# => [[4, 4, 4], [4, 8, 4], [4, 4, 4]]
```

Get three rows starting from the second, for each row get three elements starting from the first (0-based).

Answer (score 1):

The method [Matrix#minor](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html#method-i-minor) is taylor-made for this.

**Code**

```
require 'matrix'

def pull_subarray(arr, row_range, col_range)
  Matrix[*arr].minor(row_range, col_range).to_a
end
```

**Examples**

```
pull_subarray(arr, 1..-1, 2..-1)
  #=> [[1, 1],
  #    [4, 4],
  #    [8, 4],
  #    [4, 4]]

pull_subarray(arr, 1..2, 2..3)
  #=> [[1, 1],
  #    [4, 4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
arr[2..-1].map { |a| a[1..-1] }
# => [[4, 4, 4], [4, 8, 4], [4, 4, 4]]
```